# Promise is not working correctly with Firebase

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, promise

I have the following code:

```
let promises = [];
//Return first promise from DB save to zone_obj list
firebase.database().ref('node-client/images').once('value').then(function(snapshot) {
    promises.push(snapshot.val());
});
Promise.all(promises).then(values => {
    console.log(values); // zone_obj
});
```

I want to query the firebase database, and for each snapshot, add the val to an array.

I do not fully understand the idea of promises, hence why this isn't working.

Could somebody offer some explanation or an example on why this is not working/how to fix it.

I thought it would add a promise each time it gets the val and then log the values when all the promise have been added.

Comment: Push `Promise` into array. Not Promise value. `promises.push(firebase.database().ref('node-client/images').once('value'))`.

Comment: Do you get an "end" event once retrieval from DB completed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When `Promise.all()` is called in your code the `promises` array is still empty because `firebase.database().ref('node-client/images').once('value')` returns a Promise which is resolved after the database has been queried successfully.

Try calling `Promise.all()` after the array has been filled completely:

```
let promises = [];
//Return first promise from DB save to zone_obj list
firebase.database().ref('node-client/images').once('value').then(function(snapshot) {
    // Push the promises to the array
    promises.push(snapshot.val());
})
.then(function() {
    // Log the values when all promises are resolved
    Promise.all(promises).then(values => {
        console.log(values); // zone_obj
    });
});
```